# Angular JS using $resource and waiting for promise to be resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, angular-resource, angular-services

I wrote this service that uses $resource to fetch usernames using the github api

```
githubApiD3App.service('githubApiService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.GetuserNames = function(searchString){
        var githubAPI = $resource("https://api.github.com/search/users", {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, {get: { method: "JSONP"}});

        return githubAPI.get({ q: searchString});
    };
}]);
```

In my controller I am doing this

```
$scope.githubData = githubApiService.GetuserNames($scope.searchString);
```

I know a promise is being returned but I can't seem to be able to make my service wait before returning the data or my controller wait for the data. As my code stands now I immediately get an empty object as a response. I've tried using success in my controller like so

```
scope.githubData = githubApiService.GetuserNames($scope.searchString).success(callback());
```

where in the callback I return the data. However that doesn't work. I've also tried using .$promise paired with .then in my service but that doesn't work either.

So with that said, what can I do so that $scope.githubData doesn't get assigned an empty object or waits for the response?

Comment: What lib for githubApiService did you use. Give me the bower/npm link. I am gonna try your code.

Comment: No lib,  got the link straight from the github api documentation.  Google girhub api search users for the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer to my question. It is not the perfect answer only because I was trying to handle promises incorrectly to begin with. This [blog post](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) helped me better understand promises and how to handle them properly.

In the controller of my app instead of assigning a scope variable w/e the promise returned, I did this

```
githubApiService.getUsernames($scope.searchString).then(function(results){

    $scope.returnedUsers = results.data.items.splice(start, deleteCount);

    console.log($scope.returnedUsers);
});
```

I've shortened the contents of my controller, but I basically handled all manipulation of the data inside the .then callback function. This line

```
$scope.returnedUsers = results.data.items.splice(start, deleteCount);
```

works to both set the variable in the controller, within the callback, and also to populate it with the necessary data so it can be outputed in my view when I did {{githubData}}. By doing everything inside the callback function I stopped getting any errors due to undefined variables. I was getting errors because when I did something like this

```
$scope.githubData = githubApiService.GetuserNames('engineerKev').then(function(results){
console.log(results.data.items[0]);
});
$scope.githubData.data.items.sort(sortFunction);
```

$scope.githubData would be an empty object with undefined properties.

So moral of the story, and please edit my answer if I still don't get promises, is to handle your promises inside the callback function in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Man, now I can't install `$resource` but I did a similar thing using `$http`.

Check this out:

```
githubApiD3App.service('githubApiService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $http.get("https://api.github.com/search/users?q=" + searchString);
    };
}]);
```

Then using `then` I handle the results:

```
scope.githubData = githubApiService.GetuserNames('engineerKev').then(function(results){
console.log(results.data.items[0]);
});
```

and print this:

```
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "engineerKev",
      "id": 3943145,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/3943145?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/engineerKev",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/engineerKev/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false,
      "score": 40.398766
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You answer is correct, and the right output is shown in the console. I just checked; however when ever I try to display the array contained in " results.data.items " I get a {} in my view. Did you try display the output in your view?

Comment: @engineerKev Not in the view, I only printed it in the console but I guess when I see it there it would be available in the view too. If you make me a plunker I have a look again and help you. On Friday I was not on my PC, so I don't have the code.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work using a variety of ways, but I did find this while googling how to handle promises
http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html
and it gave me an idea of how to handle my situation. I will post the code as my answer. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Kev, I'm glad you finally get it. Because of the async nature of $http you of course have to handle it in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$scope.githubData = githubApiService.GetuserNames($scope.searchString);
```

is correct for 'normal' `$resource` usage. However, when combining `$resource` with `JSONP`, things could get a little funky. Try to do something like this (I added `isArray` and changed the action name to avoid potential conflicts with `$resource.get`):

```
githubApiD3App.service('githubApiService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.GetuserNames = function(searchString){
        var githubAPI = $resource("https://api.github.com/search/users", {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, {getUsers: { method: "JSONP", isArray: true}});

        return githubAPI.getUsers({ q: searchString});
    };
}]);
```

Then in the controller:

```
githubApiService.GetuserNames($scope.searchString).$promise.then(function(users){
    $scope.githubData = users;
});
```

This is a good read on the subject: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2610-using-jsonp-with-resource-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: you're answer was REALLY close. When I printed $scope.githubData in the view like so {{githubData}}, I saw the object; however when I console logged it, it was undefined and when I went to manipulate the object and the items array inside it further, I got this error:
Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
I will read your linked article and if it turns out that the answer is somewhere In there I will check off your answer as the correct one. Thanks for your help